# How to call 3rd party api like Gandi.Net from Node (server.js)

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, express, xml-rpc

I am new to Node.Js I am creating an Mean Stack application, in which I want to call 3rd party API [Gandi.Net](http://doc.rpc.gandi.net/domain/usage.html) from My Node.js code.

My Node.Js plus Express Application is getting use to make rest based API which is getting consume by my Angular client.

I found a little bit help from this link https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc. ut not so much.

Do I need to make new server for XML-RPC?
If any one have did this kind of work, then any sample application will help a lot.

If any one have made any http call from node application then sample application will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to make an http call from the node server.
You can use the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module.

The documentation has tons of examples as well.

A very simple example from the module itself

```
var request = require('request'); 
request('http://www.google.com', 
function (error, response, body
{ 
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received 

  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage. 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any sample application for that with model classes, controller and routing?

Comment: A quick search showed [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/09/mean-stack-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) sample mean stack app.